# row index exceeds matrix dimensions at scipy csr_matrix

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am new to python and pandas and I have the following problem

I have a dataset

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/nikoscha/Documents/ThesisR/dataset.csv', names=['response_nn','event','user'])
```

and I am trying to create a csr_matrix with the following code

```
# Create lists of all events, users adfnd respones
events = list(np.sort(df.event_id.unique()))
users = list(np.sort(df.user_id.unique()))
responses = list(df.responses)

# Get the rows and columns for our new matrix
rows = df.user_id.astype(float)
cols = df.event_id.astype(float)

# Contruct a sparse matrix for our users and items containing number of plays
data_sparse = sp.csr_matrix((responses, (rows, cols)), shape=(len(users), len(events)))
```

The above code works. But when I get a training dataset

```
mask = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.5
df = df[mask]
df = df.reset_index() 
df = df.drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

or just remove specific rows

```
df = df[df.responses != 2]
```

and try to construct the sparse matrix I get the following error

> ValueError: row index exceeds matrix dimensions

Can anyone explain me why? Thank you in advance

Comment: You specify `len(users)` as the matrix row dimension.  But apparently `rows` includes values that are greater than that.  (Not that it causes this error, but `rows` and `cols` should be `astype(integer)`, not float.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in scipy's doc, when csr_matrix init with this form:

csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])

In scipy.sparse.csr.py:

```
csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])  
        where `data`, `row_ind` and `col_ind` satisfy the  
        relationship `a[row_ind[k], col_ind[k]] = data[k]`.
```

and when csr init, it will check the relationships between row_ind.max() and M.

Also in scipy.sparse.coo.py:

```
if self.row.max() >= self.shape[0]:
                raise ValueError('row index exceeds matrix dimensions')
            if self.col.max() >= self.shape[1]:
                raise ValueError('column index exceeds matrix dimensions')
            if self.row.min() < 0:
                raise ValueError('negative row index found')
            if self.col.min() < 0:
                raise ValueError('negative column index found')
```

So row_ind.max(), col.ind.max() must less then M, N

All of above is because you want use the data in row_ind and col.ind as index to construct the sparse matrix.

ie:

```
a = np.random.random((8,2))
row = np.hstack((a[:,0],a[:,1]))
#row[0]=9
col = np.hstack([a[:,1],a[:,0]])
matrix = csr_matrix(([1]*row.shape[0], (row,col)),shape=(a.shape[0],a.shape[0]))
```

It works fine with row[0]=9 annotated. Hope it helps.